# Refreshing a div with php contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a webcam to take photos for a learning project I am currently working on and trying to display the images that have just been taken.

When a photo is taken its placed in a folder and wishing to display all the photos taken, inside the `<div>` I am needing to refresh will be the PHP code to display them.

I have created a simple div with an PHP file named `testdata.php` which echo's a random number to see if i could get this to work.

I originally pulled the script from a similar question on stackoverflow, but cant get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#mydiv').delay(10000).load('testdata.php');
          });
      </script>


 <div id="mydiv"></div>
```

The problem is it displays the contents of the file but it doesn't refresh it

here is the code for **testdata.php**

```
<?php
echo(rand(10,100));
?>
```

Comment: and it's not showing? how are you trying to refresh the div?

Comment: If it displays the contents, it is working fine, you have only added a delay, nothing like a repeating timeout to reload the file. You need to execute a function after a certain timeout and in that function set a new timeout so that the process keeps repeating. Don't use an interval as that can seriously mess-up things with simultaneous / overlapping requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
setInterval(function(){
     $('#mydiv').load('testdata.php');
}, 3000);
```

This will execute the function every 3 seconds.

Read more about setInterval [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: thank-you ever so much; this worked like a charm, could you please link a reference so i can read more about it as i am trying to learn as i go

Comment: @thenashone, glad i could help. I already linked a reference in my answer. Click on the link, and there's more about setInterval.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is only run once after the page loaded. You will need to execute it periodically:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#mydiv').load('testdata.php');
    }, 10000);
});
```

This will execute the load-function once every 10000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript's `setInterval` to periodically call a function to load contents from the server.

So if you want to execute the PHP script, say every 5 seconds, then you should use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             setInterval(function(){ $('#mydiv').load('testdata.php') }, 5000);
});
```